# Method Swizzling doesn't work for category of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear, method-swizzling

I use the normal swizzle method:

```
void swizzleMethod(Class class, SEL originalSelector, SEL swizzledSelector)
{
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

    BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    }
    else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}
```

I want to exchange `viewWillAppear:` with `xxx_viewWillAppear:`. So I create a category of UIViewController and create the method `xxx_viewWillAppear:`.

If I use `dispatch_once` in the `+(void)load` method to call `swizzleMethod`, everything goes wrong.

```
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        swizzleMethod([self class], @selector(viewWillAppear:), @selector(xxx_viewWillAppear:));
    });
}
```

It would call the `viewWillAppear:` in the UIViewController, and when `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` was called, `xxx_viewWillAppear` was called.

But if I put the load method in the UIViewController (not in the category), it goes right.

So, Why?

I use xcode 6 and iOS 8.

Comment: Do you import that category anywhere for it to be loaded into the Objective-C runtime and `+load` to get called?

Comment: @Jeff Do you have any idea?